# Is there a way to nullify a specific feature in test set while evaluating a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

Idea behind nullifying/ignoring a feature from test set is to understand how important is it considered by the model to predict the target variable (by comparing the evaluation metric's value). For numerical variables, I thought of setting them to 0, assuming the multiplication (with weights) would be 0 and thus it would get eliminated from the set. Is this approach right, else what should be done?
I am using tensorflow's DNNRegressor for modelling.

Comment: Have you considered other standard forms of importance measurement, i.e. p-values and correlation analysis? Removing a feature from a NN isn't as easy as setting to 0 since the bias term combined with the next layers' forward equations will still impact the prediction

Comment: please correct if i am wrong, but isn't correlation analysis a filter method for feature selection prior to model learning? i am trying to find the importance assigned by the model to features after the model has undergone training. 
also, in my case, i am working with a single hidden layer only, so is the 0-setting approach fine then?

Comment: Then I would try to instead of setting it to zero, instead setting to the feature mean so as to cancel its effect.

Comment: Can you explain how setting to the mean would have cancelling effect? Even if you can share a link to some material on the underlying theory, that would help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have concrete sources to share, but my intuition is that setting a feature to zero would not necessarily cancel out that feature but might rather be setting it to an arbitrary value. Consider the case where your feature follows a gaussian distribution centered at x with zero being on the extreme side of the tail, for instance. Then setting the feature to zero during testing would translate into a very unique feature value that may elicit a strong activation. On the other hand, setting it to its mean would practically mean a rather usual value from which no particular response occurs.

Comment: Ok, so then this approach(setting to mean) should work only if that feature is normally distributed and not otherwise.

Comment: That's true- however that's imo a safer assumption than setting it to zero. You could check for the distribution of the feature at hand and see if it's anywhere close to a normal distribution; if it's not we gotta think of something else :)

Comment: probably this is against the conventions of stackoverflow, but thanks for all your input, appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

For deep models there's no general input-independent way to do this kind of feature ablation you want (take a pretrained model and just change that feature's representation on the test set).

Instead I recommend you do training time ablation: train different variations of your model with different feature combinations and compare their validation set performances. This will actually tell you how much each feature helps.